# How to toggle a Switch in Flutter integration test

Tags: testing, flutter, e2e-testing

How to toggle a Switch in Flutter  integration test?

Tapping on the Swtich `driver.tap(switch)` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it does work. Need to wait a few milliseconds for the switch is briefly disable loading setting.

Comment: Hello, Are you able to read the state of toggle button which is ON/OFF ?

Comment: please let us know how !?